# Django -- choice field shows key, not value

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a model with a bunch of fields. Two of the fields have choices. They look like this:

```
SNAIL_MAIL_INVOICE_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

snailMailOnly = models.CharField(max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Snail Mail Only?', choices = SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES, default='Y')
snailMailInvoice = models.CharField(max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Snail Mail Invoice?', choices = SNAIL_MAIL_INVOICE_CHOICES, default='Y')
```

When I show these two values in a Django Template, I do so like this:

```
    <tr><td>Snail Mail Only?</td><td>{{contact.get_snailMailOnly_display}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Snail Mail Invoice?</td><td>{{contact.get_snailMailInvoice_display}}</td></tr>
```

The problem is that while the first field `snailMailOnly` display the choices `Yes` and `No` correctly, the second field `snailMailInvoice` ONLY shows `Y` and `N`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

**EDIT** -- adding contact model code:

```
class System_Contact(models.Model):
IS_MAIN_CONTACT_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

IS_SYSTEM_OWNER_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

IS_RESSY_CONTACT_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No, this is a commercial contact'),
)

TRADE_CHOICES = (
    ('EL', 'Electrician'),
    ('LA', 'Landscaper'),
    ('PL', 'Plumber'),
    ('TR', 'Trencher'),
)

SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

SNAIL_MAIL_INVOICE_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)


firstInitial = models.CharField(max_length = 10, verbose_name = 'First Initial', blank = True, null = True)
firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'First Name', blank = True, null = True)
lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 160, verbose_name = 'Last Name', blank = True, null = True)
phonetically = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = 'Phonetically', blank = True, null = True)
companyName = models.CharField (max_length = 160, verbose_name = 'Company Name', blank = True, null = True) #Only used for Commercial Owners, no other field needed
homePhone = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Home Phone Number', blank = True, null = True)
officePhone = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Office Phone Number', blank = True, null = True)
cellPhone = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Cell Phone Number', blank = True, null = True)
faxNumber = models.CharField (max_length= 60, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Fax Number')
isMainContact = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Is the Main Contact?', choices = IS_MAIN_CONTACT_CHOICES, default='N')
isRessyContact = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Is this a Ressy Contact?', choices = IS_RESSY_CONTACT_CHOICES, default='Y')

isArchived = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Archived?', default = False)
systemOwner = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Is a System Owner?', choices = IS_SYSTEM_OWNER_CHOICES, default='N')  #this is just a flag to say they own a system
worksFor = models.CharField (max_length = 70, verbose_name = 'Works For', blank = True, null = True)
tradeType = models.ForeignKey(Contact_Trade, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Trade')
emailAddress = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'Email Address', blank = True, null = True)

billingAddress = models.CharField(max_length = 150, verbose_name = 'Billing Address', blank=True, null=True )
billingCity = models.CharField(max_length = 90, verbose_name = 'Billing City', blank=True, null=True)
billingProvince = models.CharField(max_length = 30, verbose_name = 'Billing Province', blank=True, null=True)
billingPostalCode = models.CharField(max_length = 10, verbose_name = 'Billing Postal Code', blank=True, null=True)
snailMailOnly = models.CharField(max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Snail Mail Only?', choices = SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES, default='Y')
snailMailInvoice = models.CharField(max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Snail Mail Invoice?', choices = SNAIL_MAIL_INVOICE_CHOICES, default='Y')
```

Comment: Post the code for your contact.get_snailMailInvoice_display. The problem is probably there.

Comment: @DTing -- added the whole `contact` model. Not sure what else you're looking for. the `get_FOO_display` is a standard Django tag.

Comment: Sorry about that, bit rusty on my django. Definately try Chris Pratt's suggestion, but have you tried replacing SNAIL_MAIL_INVOICE_CHOICES with SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES in your template and seeing what happens after restart? On a side note, DEFAULT_Y_N_CHOICES instead of all those "different" choices might be something to consider?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Indeed, I'm looking at the models I created when I was first learning Django and cringe. There will be future changes to get rid of all these choice fields -- yuk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK -- I figured it out.

I realised there was something connected with the fact that in my CSV file, the `snailMailInvoice` field is the LAST field on each line. Thus, at the end of the line there is a carriage return. I assumed that this was a `\n` -- thus in my MySQL command to import the CSV, I state `terminated by '\n'`.

However, the MySQL picked up a '\r' on EVERY line and was adding it to the `snailMailInvoice` field. Thus, every record has either a `Y` or a `N` with a `\r` attached.

I amended my MySQL import statement to have: `lines terminated with '\r\n'` Now everything is working as expected.

Lesson learned.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for that based on the code you've posted. Were 'Y' and 'N' the display values for `SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES` at one point? It's possible that your web server isn't pulling the most recent code.

If you're in development, try killing runserver (CTRL+C) and restarting it.

If you're in production, restart your webserver *and* the process (if any) it proxies to, such as uwsgi.

You can also try deleting any `*.pyc` files laying around in your project. Quick and easy method in *nix shell is (from your project directory):

```
$ find . -name="*.pyc" -exec rm {}\;
```

Comment: No, the choices have always been Yes and No. I rebooted the test server (not in production yet) and there's no change. I must say I'm baffled!

Comment: Please try what Chris Pratt recommends. Rebooting the server will not remove the pre-compiled .pyc files.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also deleted the .pyc files and there is no change -- I'm still getting the `Y` or `N` -- not Yes or No.